# Get object fields from ForeignKey in RadioSelect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a model with a ForeignKey field and a form to create and update the objects.

I choose the ForeignKeyField with a RadioSelect widget and loops through the radio inputs in the template with `{% for radio in form.foreign_key_items %}{{ radio.tag }} - {{ radio.choice_label }}{% endfor %}`.

My form is:

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('foreign_key_item',)
        widgets = {'foreign_key_item': RadioSelect,}
```

But the `choice_label` is not enough information for the user to select the correct object.

How is it possible to print fields from the `foreign_key_item` objects when I print each radio?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile all the appropriate information in the view and add it to the context that is rendering the form.  Alternatively, you can probably use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: But all the forms is in a list, so I don't know how to pair the data in context data with the correct forms in my form list.